# React Native refreshing data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to refresh some data when users re-vistis the screen. The way im using other places and it works. but can't figure out why this won't fly on this screen?

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.handleDidFocus)
}
async handleDidFocus()  {
  ...
}
```

This is how I load data the first time and want to load it again when users revisits.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.getGroupAccepted();
}

async getGroupAccepted() {
  if (this.state.token == null) {
    var token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    this.setState({ "token": token });
  }

  fetch('https://.../api/group/getActive', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      token: this.state.token
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      groups_accepted: data.groups_active,
      loading: false,
    });
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling getGroupAccepted?

Comment: Have you tried moving `addListener` function outside of `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: @AdrianLineweaver I'm calling it in componentWillMount() { this.getGroupAccepted(); }

Comment: @UzairA. where should I move it to?

Comment: Try moving to `componentDidMount`

Comment: @varit05 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:2) TypeError: this.getGroupAccepted is not a function. (in 'this.getGroupAccepted()', this.getGroupAccepted is undefined) handleDidFocus ... tryCatch ...

Comment: Please call `getGroupAccepted()` instead of `this.getGroupAccepted()`

Comment: @varit05 Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:1) ReferenceError: Can't find variable getGroupAccepted. Method look like this:     async handleDidFocus()  { getGroupAccepted() }

Comment: Can you please create expo app on snack.expo.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked. Now when a user revisits the screen it loads the data once again.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this._handleDataChange)
}

_handleDataChange = () => {
  this.getGroupAccepted();
}
```